# Edit docx and save it as pdf in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pdf, docx

I'm doing some bulk editing of documents (docx because the documents have some detailed graphic layout which I can only do in Word. Thus, Latex is not an option for me. Also Pages is not an option, because I have to programatically edit the docs). I'm using `python-docx` without any problem.

The problem appears when I try to save it in pdf. I'm in macOS Ventura 13.4 with Word for
Mac 16.74.

I already tried `docx2pdf` but I'm always getting an error "Error: Message not understood.". I then moved to invoke an `AppleScript`

```
def run_applescript_wordsaveaspdf(doc_filepath, pdf_filepath):
    doc_filepath = doc_filepath.replace("/", ":").strip(":")
    pdf_filepath = pdf_filepath.replace("/", ":").strip(":")

    applescript = f"""
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        set theDoc to open "{doc_filepath}"
        delay 2 -- wait for the document to open
        set theActiveDoc to the active document
        set pdfPath to "{pdf_filepath}"
        save as theActiveDoc file name pdfPath file format format PDF
        close theActiveDoc
    end tell
    """
    osa_command = ['osascript', '-e', applescript]
    result = subprocess.run(osa_command, text=True, capture_output=True)
    # Check for errors
    if result.stderr:
        raise Exception(f"AppleScript Error: {result.stderr}")
    return result
```

, but I'm getting some errors (mostly "*345:406: execution error: Microsoft Word got an error: missing value doesn’t understand the “save as” message. (-1708)\n*"). I also tried with a slightly different format to save the file `save as theActiveDoc file format format PDF file name pdfPath` but I get the same error, and with the following instruction `export theActiveDoc as PDF file name pdfPath`, in which case I get the following error: "*352:364: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier. (-2741)\n*"

Although I can't reproduce it, there were a few times where this has worked fine and I can save the pdf. Can anyone help me here?